# Can't connect components with mapDispatchToProps

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have React Native project with Redux and I'm trying to connect the actions to the components.
I have `App.js` file without `index.js` file.

This is how I implement Redux:

`App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './src/store/Store.js';
import AppNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator';

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <Provider store = { store }>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

`AppNavigator.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: MainTabNavigator
  })
);
```

`MainTabNavigator.js`: (Only the relevant part)

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {HomeScreen} from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import * as CounterActions from '../store/actions/CounterActions';

let HomePage = connect(state => mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomePage,
    },
    config
);

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  SettingsStack,
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        count: state.counter.count
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    ...CounterActions
};

export default tabNavigator;
```

`CounterActions.js`:

```
export const increment = (number) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT', number })
    }
};

export const decrement = (number) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT', number })
    }
};
```

The following line in `MainTabNavigator.js` connects the state to props of the HomeScreen component: 
`let HomePage = connect(state => mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);`

`HomeScreen.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(props));
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>COUNT FROM STORE: {props.count}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

HomeScreen components gets the state correctly and render 'count', but How do I connect the actions?

I want HomeScreen to dispatch like this:

```
props.increment(1);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `mapDispatchToProps` is the second argument of the `connect` function from the `react-redux.`

I also think that you pass wrong the first argument to the `connect`.

Try this:

```js
let HomePage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've already tried this but it doesn't work...

Comment: And what was the problem? `props.increment` was undefined? Was there any error in console?

Answer (score 1):

Follow along, we will make some modifications to your files:

First lets modify your `MainTabNavigator.js` since you only posted the relevant part, make sure to implement this for the rest as well.

```
import React from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {HomeScreen} from '../screens/HomeScreen';

let HomePage = connect(state => mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen); // <===== Remove this

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomePage, // <===== Make this HomeScreen instead of HomePage
    },
    config
);

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  SettingsStack,
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        count: state.counter.count
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    ...CounterActions
};

export default tabNavigator;
```

What we want is to have the mapping of state and props on the Home Screen itself (or any other screen)

Now lets move on to your `HomeScreen.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { increment, decrement } from '../store/actions/CounterActions';  // <===== import your actions here, preferably like this


/** add the following: */

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    // ... computed data from state and optionally ownProps
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    // ... normally is an object full of action creators
    increment,    // <===== Map your dispatch here to props
    decrement     // <===== Mapping the second dispatch
};

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(props));
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>COUNT FROM STORE: {props.count}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

/** Export your component like this */ 

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeScreen)
```

Now anywhere on your `HomeScreen.js` you can call `this.props.increment(yourNumber)` or `this.props.decrement(yourNumber)` and you should be good to go

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I did that but it still not working. I can't export default `HomeScreen` with the `connect`. Thanks a lot anyway!!

Comment: You are most welcome. but just for clarification, once you follow this you dont need to `export default HomeScreen` anymore instead you export the connect. look at the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it by the following way:

`MainTabNavigator.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {HomeScreen} from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import {increment, decrement} from '../store/actions/CounterActions';

let HomePage = connect(state => mapStateToProps, dispatch => mapDispatchToProps(dispatch))(HomeScreen);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: HomePage,
    },
    config
);

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  SettingsStack,
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        count: state.counter.count
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        increment: (number) => dispatch(increment(number)),
        decrement: (number) => dispatch(decrement(number))
    }
};

export default tabNavigator;
```

Comment: As I stated in my answer above, you are adding another functions which are not necessary. This is enough `let HomePage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);`. Moreover `mapStateToProps` can take multiple arguments, so when you will need it in future and do it your way, you will need to add these arguments also to your function which is first argument of `connect` in your implementation. If it is not working the way I suggest, the problem is somewhere else, not here.